# Powershell parameter manipulation

Tags: powershell

PS Noob - Not sure what this sort of thing is even called.

Want to iterate (?!) thru many `-identity` parameters. For example, I need to give Joe rights to a large number of Distro Lists.

```
Add-ADPermission -Identity "Dallas Red Team" -User "JoeB" -AccessRights WriteProperty -Properties "Member"
```

"Dallas" and "Team" are constant but the team color is variable.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I 'm not sure why foloks think this is a programming question??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how complex your operation is, a spreadsheet (CSV) can be used to import data into PowerShell.  In conjunction with a `foreach` loop, you should be able to tackle what you are looking to do.

Example CSV data:

```
Name,UserID,Group
"Joe Biden","JoeB","Dallas Red Team"
"Joe Biden","JoeB","Dallas Green Team"
"Joe Biden","JoeB","Dallas Blue Team"
```

Example PowerShell:

```
> Import-Csv "C:\users\user\desktop\Dallas.csv" | Foreach { Add-ADPermission -Identity $_.Group -User $_.UserID }
```

Example PowerShell to list all "Dallas" groups:

> Get-ADGroup -Anr "Dallas" | FL

Callouts:

- Import-Csv cmdlet stores the contents of a CSV file in an array in PowerShell.  You can bind this to a variable as well should you choose.
- `|` (pipe) chains two commands together.  In the example, you first load up the data you want to use, then you pipe it to actions.
- `Foreach` goes through each line of the array and performs the command in curlies `{ }`.
- `$_.` prefix means the current object. This effectively tells the command to use the current value for the referenced Column, for the current line of the foreach loop that is running.
- `Get-ADGroup -Anr` ANR is Ambiguous Name Resolution.  It can be pretty iffy at times, but if you can dial in the output in a separate query first, you can use it to generate a target list of Groups.  You could also pipe the output to Export-Csv to generate your CSV file for later Import.  Classy!

Comment: Yes, I had thought of some sort of an array but the point was to avoid typing in hundreds of DL names. Was hoping there was some sort of wildcard that would ignore or assume the variable portion of the identity parameter. Joe only needs to be applied to every "Dallas*Team" - the color of the team, in this case is not important.

Comment: You can try Get-ADGroup -Anr Dallas. If this returns only the groups you want, you could pipe the list to a similar command

Comment: Ambiguous Name Resolution is fun, but not terribly reliable. Try the Get- command first by itself.

Comment: Perfect - I was thinking of something similar with an ldap query tool but realized I'm in over my head. Get- works fine and then easy to tweak the .csv